# Multiple values of the same column name in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlcommand

this might seem like a weird question, earlier I posted another question on ASP multiple values through a session variable, I've now figured that out and have managed to pass all three values for instance to a label. Now however I need to pass the three IDs to create a gridview for the three values... So for my SQL statement I have:

`SelectCommand="SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE ([BookID] = ?)">`

So I need there to be 3 BookID=?,?,? for instance, is this possible?

Or is there another way to do it in ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain by your question, but I think you're after an `IN` statement

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE ([BookID] in (1,2,3)">
```

Answer (score 2):

i think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE [BookID] in (?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can use the 'IN' operator to do it. The SQL query would be

```
SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE [BookID] IN (@Book1,@Book2,@Book3)
```

You will have to pass the book1,2,3 as parameters to the asp function. You might have to construct the query dynamically by appending the parameters. Something like this

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE [BookID] IN ({0},{1},{2})",book1,book2,book3)
```

Comment: You should use the IN operator, but be wary of just putting string variables straight into your SQL query - that makes you vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @vincebowden----I absolutely agree with you. But in this case, it looks like an academic project. In most professional projects the query would be issued using L2S or stored procs or other tech.

Comment: @vincebowden --- I gave you a +1 for pointing out the sql injection attack